# Viewing comments from giant CSV file in R

Tags: r, unix, csv

I have a massive CSV file that is too large to open in any text editor on my standard laptop.  However, I am able to import the file into R and subset for use... but I cannot view the comments within the CSV.  According to the CSV associated README file, there is essential information regarding the data version in the comments.  The informative header lines start with '#%' and the comments start with '##'.  I figure if I can just view the first 20 lines of code starting with '#' I will be able to extract the information I need.

The R help documentation for grep and head is unclear to me, but I did find a nice website describing how to do what I want in Unix (here:  http://bconnelly.net/working-with-csvs-on-the-command-line/).

The Unix code used to print all rows that start with '#' is:   grep "#" input.csv

Can anyone tell me how to do this in R? Or at least how to print lines starting with '#' in the first say 20 rows?

Comment: It's almost certainly worth checking the number of rows in your csv file, and the number of rows that R loads. You don't specify how you are loading your data, but read.csv has an option comment.char to specify a comment character. See ?read.csv

Comment: `grep("^#", readLines("filename.csv"), value=TRUE)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr 's comment is the correct answer.  Using `readlines` avoids the potential hiccups with row lengths and comment chars that one deals with when using, e.g., `read.table`

Comment: It's not clear to me what OS you have, but potentially `readLines(pipe(system('grep "#" input.csv')))`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, post your comment as answer?  Might be worth including `n=20` if OP wants to avoid reading the whole file into memory again ...

Comment: @BenBolker aye. I'll collect all these and mebbe add another as well.

Answer (score 5):

One initial "R" way to do it is:

```
grep("^#", readLines("filename.csv"), value=TRUE)
```

As Ben Bolker pointed out, you can add a limit to `readLines` to prevent R from creating a potentially large, temporary object:

```
grep("^#", readLines("filename.csv", n=20), value=TRUE)
```

Ben also pointed out how to do it using Unix `grep` (if that's available on the system in question):

```
readLines(pipe(system('grep "^#" input.csv')))
```